# How to create an object with optional functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a custom JS+CSS library to be able to write something like this:

```
var myObj = myLibrary( '.my-div' );
console.log( myObj ); //HTML nodeList
myObj.someFunction(); //perform some action with the node
```

Is this possible to make?

Things I tried:

```
var myLibrary = function( el ){
  return document.querySelectorAll( el );
}
var myObj = myLibrary( '.my-div' );
console.log( myObj ); //HTML nodeList, ok!
myObj.someFunction(); //undefined, nope :(
```

Comment: You can add a function an object `obj.someFunction = function() {}`, but you do not try to do that in your code, so how should that magically happen?

Comment: What do you mean with `optional functions`?

Comment: I mean that I need a type of object (for example a nodeList) to be able to call an inner function.
If I just create an object with functions in it, logging that object would log a generic JS object. I want a NodeList object.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll( el )` gives your the list of the matching nodes. So, you won't get a single node. So you'll have to loop through all these nodes to add function to them.

Most the function are there for nodes. And you won't be able to able to use them on the returned node list. As it is an array.. in simple words. In short, get elements/node from this returned `array` and use properties on them

Example

```js
var myLibrary = function( el ){
  return document.querySelectorAll( el );
}
var nodes = myLibrary( '.test' );
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i].style.color =  colors[colors.length % i];
}
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the function you want to your object (in this case the node list):

```js
function myLibrary(el) {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(el) // save the node list in a variable
  list.someFunction = function() { // add the function(s)  you want to that object
    console.dir(this)
  }
  return list // return the object
}
var myObj = myLibrary('.my-div')
console.log(myObj)
myObj.someFunction()
```

It would also be possible to extend the `prototype` of the `NodeList` but you really should not do that, because this could result into naming conflicts and hard to trace problems.

Comment: Thank you!
But what happens exactly when you call list.someFunction = function() {} ?
Does the new property "someFunction" get added to the object "list" since it's a JS object?